Superimposed triangles
Because \$k^2\$ is the sum of the \$k\$ first odd positive integers, squared numbers can be represented as ASCII-art triangles of height \$k\$ as follows:
1²=1   2²=4   3²=9    4²=16  ...

                        *
                *      ***
         *     ***    *****
  *     ***   *****  *******

Besides, any positive integer \$n\$ can be represented as a sum of squares by iteratively subtracting the highest square less than or equal to \$n\$.
For instance: \$119=10^2+4^2+1^2+1^2+1^2\$
Note that this is a greedy algorithm which is not necessarily the shortest possible sum which, according to Lagrange's four-square theorem, never exceeds 4 terms (e.g. \$119=10^2+3^2+3^2+1^2\$).
Task
Given an integer \$n\ge1\$, output an ASCII-art made by superimposing the triangles representing the squares of the greedy decomposition described above.
The triangles must be bottom-aligned and horizontally centered.
The first triangle is filled with \$1\$'s. The second triangle turns the \$1\$'s into \$2\$'s. The third triangle turns the \$2\$'s into \$3\$'s, and so forth.
It is assumed that the input is such that its greedy decomposition does not exceed \$9\$ squares1.
Standard I/O rules apply. Extra leading and/or trailing whitespace is acceptable as long as the output is well formatted.
1. According to A006892, the smallest integer for which 10 squares are required is \$453694852221687377444001767\$.
Test cases
Input: 1
1

Input: 9
  1
 111
11111

Input: 13
  1
 121
12221

Input: 119
         1
        111
       11111
      1111111
     111111111
    11111111111
   1111112111111
  111111222111111
 11111122222111111
1111112225222111111

Input: 165
           1
          111
         11111
        1111111
       111111111
      11111111111
     1111111111111
    111111111111111
   11111111211111111
  1111111122211111111
 111111112232211111111
11111111223432211111111


Charcoal, 24 bytes
ＮθＷ⌊₂θ«≧⁻×ιιθＧ←↗↘←ιＩ⊕ΣＫＫ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｎθ

Input n.
Ｗ⌊₂θ«

Repeat until n's square root is zero. (Floating-point inaccuracy would apply after 2¹⁰⁶.)
≧⁻×ιιθ

Subtract the square of that from n.
Ｇ←↗↘←ιＩ⊕ΣＫＫ

Draw a centred triangle of that size using the next digit.

Jelly,  24  21 bytes
Æ½²ạƊƬIN½r1RṠSz⁶UŒBṚY

A full program that accepts a positive integer and prints the triangle.
Try it online!
How?
Calculate the squares, then for each create half the triangle back-to-front and upside-down using ones, then add these up and rotate and reflect to produce the full, superimposed triangle:
e.g. \$22 = 4^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2\$:
       squares: [4,                            2,          1,    1]
half-triangles: [[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1],[1]],[[1,1],[1]],[[1]],[[1]]]
        summed:  [[4,2,1,1],[2,1,1],[1,1],[1]]
 fill & rotate:  [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[2,1,1,0],[4,2,1,1]]
       reflect:  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,2,1,1,0],[1,1,2,4,2,1,1]]
   print lines:     1   
                   111  
                  11211 
                 1124211

Æ½²ạƊƬIN½r1RṠSz⁶UŒBṚY - Link: positive integer, N
     Ƭ                - collect until a fixed point under:
    Ɗ                 -   last three links as a monad - f(Current):
Æ½                    -     integer square root {Current}
  ²                   -     squared
   ạ                  -     absolute difference {Current}
      I               - forward differences
       N              - negated
        ½             - square rooted
         r1           - range to 1 (vectorises)
           R          - range
            Ṡ         - signs
             S        - sum (vectorises)
              z⁶      - transpose filling with space characters
                U     - reverse each
                 ŒB   - bounce each
                   Ṛ  - reverse
                    Y - join with newline characters


Do you think there's any potential with something like Æ½²ạƊƬUIÆ½ŻIUx@RUƤz⁶z⁶UŒBY (26) Try it online? I mostly based that off of yours and I've never touched Jelly before so maybe it could end up shorter than 21, I don't know. It's using the method of my Uiua solution, roughly

@noodleperson, you could golf that to 22 as Æ½²ạƊƬIN½RṠSṚṚƤz⁶ZUŒBY. Our methods are just doing things in a different order from each other.

@JonathanAllan Now both say 4. ;)

JavaScript (Node.js), 90 bytes
f=(m,i=n=r=m,t=(g=v=>i*i>m?--i?v+g(v)+v:v+'':g(-~v,m-=i*i,r-=i+i-1))` `)=>r?f(r,n)+`
`+t:t

Try it online!
f=(
  m,   // number for render
  i=   // loop from width (`n`) to 1
  n=   // width of output
  r=m, // remaining number for next (upper) line
  t=(  // current line
    g= // loop for `i`
    v=> // value for current (most left / right side) character
      i*i>m?
        // do not need another triangle
        // render a single character if it is center
        // or pair of characters with recursive for their center
        --i?v+g(v)+v:v+'':
        // do need another triangle
        // value for render increased
        // update `m` and `r` accordingly
        g(-~v,m-=i*i,r-=i+i-1)
    )` ` // initially, the character for render is a space
  )=>
    r? // if there are number remaining for next (upper) line
      f(r,n)+`\n`+t: // render next (upper) line then current one
      t // that is last line now


Uiua, 41 35 33 32 bytes
⍉⊂⇌⊸↘1⍉⬚@ ⧅⇌+@1⊚⇌⧈-[⍥(⊃-√⊸⍜√⌊)∞]

Try it: Uiua pad.
-2 thanks to ovs.
Explanation: Consider the input 119.
The greedy square-finding algorithm is implemented by repeatedly subtracting the greatest square less than N until a fixed point is reached, collecting intermediate square roots in an array. The greatest square less than N is retrieved by ⍜√⌊ - "under square root floor", meaning take the square root, floor it (round it down to an integer), and square it again.
      [⍥(⊃-√⊸⍜√⌊)∞] 119
[0 0 1 1 1 4 10]

We take the consecutive differences:
      ⧈-
[0 1 0 0 3 6]

Reversing this and passing it to ⊚ where, which keeps A[i] copies of each index i of A, gives the left-half of the bottom row:
      ⇌
[6 3 0 0 1 0 0]
      ⊚
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 4]
      +@1
"1111112225"

Reversing each prefix of this string, padding with spaces, gives the right-half of the triangle:
      ⬚@ ⧅⇌
╭─              
╷ "1         "  
  "11        "  
  "111       "  
  "1111      "  
  "11111     "  
  "111111    "  
  "2111111   "  
  "22111111  "  
  "222111111 "  
  "5222111111"  
               ╯

The last thing to do is reflect the array horizontally, and the task is complete:
      ⍉⊂⇌⊸↘1⍉
╭─                       
╷ "         1         "  
  "        111        "  
  "       11111       "  
  "      1111111      "  
  "     111111111     "  
  "    11111111111    "  
  "   1111112111111   "  
  "  111111222111111  "  
  " 11111122222111111 "  
  "1111112225222111111"  
                        ╯


I think you can do un\+ for consecutive differences

@ovs Right you are. I forgot about that inverse, nice spot.

05AB1E, 22 bytes
ΔDtïDˆn-}¯üαÅ1ƶ˜η€ûJ.c

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Step 1: Get the greedy list of squares:
Δ        # Loop until the result no longer changes (using the implicit input)
 D       #  Duplicate the current integer
  t      #  Take the square-root of the copy
   ï     #  Floor it to an integer
    Dˆ   #  Add a copy of that to the global array
      n  #  Take the square of that floored square root
       - #  Subtract it from the current integer for the next iteration
}¯       # After the changes-loop: push the global array
         #  e.g. input=119 → [10,4,1,1,1,0]

Try just step 1 online.
Step 2: Create the first halve of the bottom row of the output:
üα       # For each overlapping pair: get its absolute difference
         #  → [6,3,0,0,1]
  Å1     # Convert each value to a list of that many 1s
         #  → [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1],[],[],[1]]
    ƶ    # Multiply each inner value with its 1-based index
         #  → [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2],[],[],[5]]
     ˜   # Flatten this list of lists
         #  → [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5]

Try just the first two steps online.
Step 3: Use it to create the entire triangle and format it to the correct output:
η        # Get the prefixes of this list
         #  → [[1],[1,1],...,[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5]]
 €û      # Palindromize each inner list
         #  → [[1],[1,1,1],...,[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
   J     # Join each inner list together to a string
         #  → ["1","111",...,"1111112225222111111"]
    .c   # Centralize; join this list by newlines,
         # and add leading spaces to center all lines
         #  → "         1
         #             111
         #             ...
         #     1111112225222111111"
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)


JavaScript (Node.js), 131 bytes
f=(n,i=m=n,A=(e=[...Array(2*m)]).fill(e))=>n?i*i>n?f(n,i-1,A):f(n-i*i,i,A.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>-~c-(x+y<3*m-i|y-x<m-i)||' '))):A

Try it online!

J, 59 bytes
[:|.' 123456789'{~[:+/@(i.@->/0{|@i:)1+2%:2-/\(-<.&.%:)^:a:

Try it online!

Greedily finds the biggest squares
Successive differences
Take first (largest) square, say 4, and create 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4, then create a "less than table" between that and, say 3 2 1 0, where one list is constructed counting down for each of the squares.  This results in a "plane" for each square, consisting of the triangular pattern we want, but upside down.
Add the planes together
Convert to ascii
Reverse


Retina, 81 80 bytes
.+
*
L$`(\G_|\1__)+
$#1*
\G_(?<=(_+))(?=(_*¶\1)*)
$.(_$#2*
L^$`\d
$.`* $^$%'$<%'

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
.+
*

Convert n to unary.
L$`(\G_|\1__)+
$#1*

Greedily decompose n into positive squares, still in unary.
\G_(?<=(_+))(?=(_*¶\1)*)
$.(_$#2*

Count the number of squares that overlap each position, starting from the centre working out, in decimal.
L^$`\d
$.`* $^$%'$<%'

Turn the string of counts into the final triangle; this is the main reason I've used Retina 1 since mirroring is tricky at best in Retina 0.8.2.

APL+WIN, 97 bytes
Prompts for integer
r←0⍴0
n←⎕
:while n≠0
r←r,i←⌊n*.5
n←n-i*2
:end
(' ',(⍕⍳⌈/,n)~' ')[1+(0 ¯1↓⌽n),n←⊖+⌿⊃m∘.≤¨⌽¨m←⍳¨,r]

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Japt -R, 29 bytes
Was tapping away at this over the weekend and then got beaten to the punch by a very similar solution.
9ÆµNpU¬f)Ì²ÃNäa ËçEÃÅ¬å+ ù Ëê

Try it
9ÆµNpU¬f)Ì²ÃNäa ËçEÃÅ¬å+ ù Ëê     :Implicit input of integer U
9Æ                                :Map the range [0,9)
 µ                                :  Decrement U by
  N                               :    Array of all inputs (i.e., [U] initially)
   p                              :    Push
    U¬                            :      Square root of U
      f                           :      Floor
       )                          :    End push
        Ì                         :    Last element
         ²                        :    Squared
          Ã                       :End map
           Nä                     :Consecutive pairs of array reduced by
             a                    :  Absolute difference
               Ë                  :Map each D at 0-based index E
                çE                :  E repeated D times
                  Ã               :End map
                   Å              :Slice off first element
                    ¬             :Join
                     å+           :Cumulatively reduce by concatenating
                        ù         :Left pad each with spaces to the length of the longest
                          Ë       :Map
                           ê      :  Palindromise
                                  :Implicit output joined with newlines


Does it fail for n<4?

As Arnauld pointed out, you do need the A at the start because when N<4 the array is too short and the consecutive-differences doesn't work as expected. 10 is a good amount because there won't be more than 9 squares

Japt -R, 33 29 bytes
AÆµV=U¬f ²V¬Ãä- ËçEÄÃ¬å+ mê û

Try it
Thanks to Shaggy for -4 with some nice Japt knowledge.
I haven't used Japt in quite a while and I remembered that it had functions to palindromize a string and center-pad an array, so this seemed like a good opportunity to pick it back up.

28 bytes

@Shaggy Of course, getting the prefixes by cumulatively reducing by concatenation, smart! And good idea to just use the input for the range, since extra zeroes don't matter.

Seems like the update makes it fail for n<4.

@Arnauld Ooh, good catch. It's because previously it always got exactly ten potentially-zero squares, but Shaggy's golf switched it to use the input as the number of squares to get, which then causes it to fail for N<4 because the array is too short for another operation later. Thanks for noticing, the fix is literally one character so I'll just edit it now :)
